# In javascript, can I determine the ACTUAL padding of a table cell?

Tags: javascript, dom

Can I determine the actual padding in effect for a cell?

I know about style.leftPadding, for example, but AFAICT that only reflects a padding value that was explictly set  with in-line styling or javascript.  It does not seem to reflect padding that was applied by style sheets.

I also know about clientWidth and offsetWidth, but I don't think those are useful either.

Thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.getComputedStyle

Comment: Combined with [currentStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IE

Comment: Mfrog, post as an answer and I can give you rep.

Answer (score -1):

you can get the table cell padding(inner) by document.all.youtableid.cellPadding

or you can move through the every cell by dom and get the padding

Comment: I don't think that's a solution. I get get a reference to a cell and inspect cell.cellpadding, or cell.style.xxxxpadding, but these only reflect the in-line specified padding, not the actual padding.

Comment: This won't give you the actual padding on the cell, downvoted